# Is there a way of completely replacing the SQL of a View with my own custom string?

Tags: 7, views, database

Recently I completed a rather complicated View, with plenty of relationships, filters, etc. I needed the View for its elegant page system. Is there a way, after seeing the SQL string, that I complete my string in MySQL, and with minimal change, use it in `db_query` standard format to replace the SQL string of the View? I know about `hook_query_alter` and `hook_view_query_alter` but it is too much abstract than a simple SQL-string, mainly if I already have the string almost complete from the Views UI.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Don't do that.** You've got two options: either use Views or don't.

## Option 1: Use a custom block/page handler

You can build your own query and theme it any way you want it. Just build it as a block or a custom page and do it the "old-fashioned" way. It will be much cleaner than trying to use views.

## Option 2: Use Views

If you want views, then you should build any additional plugins, handlers, or add any alters you need and do it right (that includes using the DB abstraction layer). This isn't hard and there is plenty of documentation floating around that can help you with this.

If you circumvent the systems you have (e.g. Views), you will end up producing code that isn't maintainable by someone else or could unknowingly introduce problems. Please don't look for shortcuts, do it well and do it right.

Comment: +1 Great advice for pretty much everything Drupal. Just because you could do something does not mean you should.

Comment: Yes, great advice, but the problem is that I think that I will use **Option 1**, as there are some performance issues in the Views SQL. The problem is that, for the site I am talking about, I only need (by now) the Domain modules, the form APIs, and the rest will come directly from the database. What is the sense of Drupal, then?

Comment: Drupal provides many things out of the box that a useful application can harness. Views + caching can be pretty fast and often times more than make up for any loss due to the verbosity of the queries.

Comment: Well, I have a View that has been made carefully. It takes 4.3 seconds to perform the query, as checked with phpMyAdmin and SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE. I have made the `db_query` myself, and it takes just 0.002 seconds, i.e., 2.000 times faster. Just a few relationships to make even the fields appear to be selected, and the fields added to the display box. Nothing else, and it takes 4 seconds. So, yes, there is a very serious problem with which you call `verbosity`.

Comment: Are you querying custom tables or standard Drupal tables and field data? That is, did you write custom fields or handlers for this? What type of data are you querying?